# Can I pass a 'theme-hint' to Keycloak, something like kc_idp_hint

Tags: keycloak

When I know I want to login through a specific IDP, I can pass a value to kc_idp_hint and that will immediately go to the selected IDP.

But now, when I want to use Keycloaks' internal authentication, I want to be able to pass a value to dynamically select a Keycloak theme. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the default Keycloak template provider you can't dynamically change the theme based on an URI parameter.

But, you can easily implement a custom template provider, which can access the URI context to dynamically load a theme.

Here is the documentation on how to build and deploy custom providers : https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_providers

And here is an example of someone who built a template provider similar to what you want to achieve : https://github.com/dteleguin/keycloak-dynamic-branding